# When should const_iterator be used instead of auto

Tags: c++, c++11

Below is an example that I think illustrates a case where it is preferable to use const_iterator to "const auto". This is because containers don't provide a cfind() function. Is there any alternative? Or should "const auto" be used and the lack of const be ignored?

```
std::string GetJobTitle(const std::string& employee)
{
    using EmployeeTitles = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
    EmployeeTitles employees = { { "Alice", "Director" },{ "Bob","Manager" } ,{ "Charlie", "Developer" } };

    // Option 1. const_iterator is access only:
    EmployeeTitles::const_iterator itr = employees.(employee);
    if (itr != employees.cend())
    {
        itr->second = "Project Manager"; // error C2678: The compiler prevents us changing the job tile which is what we want
        return itr->second;
    }

    // Option 2. const auto is more concise but is not as safe:
    const auto& itr2 = employees.find(employee);
    if (itr2 != employees.cend())
    {
        itr2->second = "Project Manager"; // employee now has new title - how can we prevent this with the compiler but still use auto?
        return itr2->second;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: It's the same as doing a foreach(const auto ...) and doing an if condition inside, compared to a function that does something similar underneath the hood...

Comment: In C++17 you can say `std::as_const(employees).find(key)` to get a const iterator out.

Comment: std::as_const is a great solution, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### If possible sidestep the problem

**Use `const` variables**

Your example doesn’t illustrate a good case for the problem. Just be more “aggressive” with constness and it disappears. You do not change `employees` at all, so the proper solution is to declare it `const` in the first place:

```
const EmployeeTitles employees = ...;
```

That’s even safer because it prevents changes to `employees` anywhere, not just changes through the iterator.

**Use scoping to separate const/non-const code**

What if you cannot make `employees` const because you can only populate it piece by piece; for example because you pull the information from a database? Move the populating code into a builder function. Or for simple cases use an immediately invoked lambda:

```
const EmployeeTitles employees = [] {
    EmployeeTitles employees;

    for (const auto& record : database.employees()) {
        // Probably some more processing would be done here in the real world.
        employees.emplace(record.name(), record.job_title());
    }

    return employees;
}();
```

**Use `const` member functions**

If `employees` is a member variable of a class and you iterate over it in a member function, make that function `const`.

**As a general rule**

Whenever you run into this problem or something similar, think of ways to use `const` variables/functions and/or scoping to sidestep it altogether. That will take care of the majority of cases.

### What if you *do* run into it?

In that case I’d go with your option 1: **Explicitely declaring the iterator `const_iterator` in combination with the `using` declaration for the map type.** It’s concise, readable, immediately understandable, and the most direct way to express your intent.

Other solutions that manipulate the constness of `employees` aren’t as good because that’s not what you really care about. What you *actually* want is a read-only iterator. Fiddling with the constness of `employees` is just a roundabout way to reach that goal. And roundabout code is harder to understand.

On the other hand that doesn’t mean you’ll run into huge problems with clarity. Especially `std::as_const` is nice and concise as well.

However with a pre-C++17 code base you’d have to use a `const_cast`. It’s a benign one because it *adds* const and it’s not too verbose, either. But I’d avoid it on the general principle that seeing a `const_cast` in a piece of code is always a bit scary on first glance. Another good possibility, as @Swift pointed out in the comments, is to implement your own version of `as_const`.

Comment: wait, why you need c++17 for that? if for as_const only, that's implementable for pre-C++17. Imho, good style is to implement things that are possible but not standardized yet, offering compiler to throw them away when switching to supported standard